# Simple/natural questions in group theory whose answers depend on set theory

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, set-theory

Take these two questions:

1. "Given objects $X$, is there always a group $(X, e, *)$ with those objects?” (Ans: yes iff Axiom of Choice.)
2. "Take a group $G$, its automorphism group ${\rm Aut}(G)$, the automorphism group of that ${\rm Aut}({\rm Aut}(G))$, ${\rm Aut}({\rm Aut}({\rm Aut}(G)))$, etc.: does this automorphism tower terminate (count it as terminating when successive groups are iso)?"  (Ans, Hamkins: Yes, but the very same group can lead to towers with wildly different heights in different set theoretic universes.)

Now, these two *questions* should be readily understood by a student who has just met a small amount of group theory in an introductory course, though their *answers* depend on set theoretic ideas going far beyond the little bit that appears in their introductory text (e.g. Alan Beardon's  first year Cambridge text *Algebra and Geometry*). The question arising:

> What other questions in group theory are there that would also strike a near-beginning student as simple and natural, and  similarly involve more or less significant amounts of set theory in their answers?

Comment: $+1$. The first one doesn't really require set theory for its answer, though. The answer, as far as the near-beginning student is concerned, is "yes", and you need set theory only to analyze whether the proof of this answer requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: Fair comment, @joriki -- maybe a looser "involve" would be better than "require" to gesture in the right direction!

Comment: Whitehead's problem (if every ses of Abelian groups $0\to\Bbb Z\to B\to A\to 0$ splits, must $A$ be free? Equivalently is every compact path connected abelian topological group a product of circles?) is a famous example, but I suppose it's too advanced for your question

Comment: Here's another one, which might fit your question better. For a group $G$ define its dual $G^\ast=\mathrm{Hom}(G,\Bbb Z)$, just like for vector spaces there is a canonical homomorphism $G\to G^{\ast\ast}$ given by $g\mapsto(f\mapsto f(g))$ and a group is called reflexive if this map is an isomorphism. Question: is every free Abelian group reflexive? Answer: yes iff there are no measurable cardinals.

Comment: Not really group theory (more general algebra) but one result that blew my mind is: if $R_n=\mathbb{R}[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ is the ring of real polynomials in $n$-variables and $Q_n$ is its field of fractions, then the projective dimension of $Q_n$ over $R_n$ is $\min(n, t+1)$ where $t$ is such that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_t$. In other word, the result (which is a single natural number) heavily depends on the continuum hypothesis: http://algebra.msri.org/ShowFile?aid=15.0

Comment: Both Shelah and Magidor *love* the connections of set theory to group theory. So you can find *a lot* of their work connecting set theory to group theory.

Comment: Related to my answer and @Asaf's comment, Eklof and Mekler asked in their book whether there is a reflexive group with cardinality the least measurable, a question which was answered affirmatively by Shelah, who also showed that it is consistent to have reflexive groups of arbitrarily large cardinality. As far as I know it is still open whether "there are reflexive groups of arbitrarily large cardinality" is a theorem of ZFC

Comment: Do you have a reference for your second mentioned problem? I've heard of Hamkins solving it, but not of the dependence on the universe.

Comment: @Wojowu Try e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9808094.pdf or for headlines, these slides from a talk http://jdh.hamkins.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/AutoTowers-Bristol-2012.pdf

Comment: @PeterSmith Thanks! I've seen the paper you've linked, but apparently I have never scrolled down far enough to see the independence result.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of my favourite results, told to me by my advisor over coffee once.

Let $G$ be an abelian group. We say that it has a norm if there is a function $\nu\colon G\to\Bbb R$ whose behaviour is what you'd expect from "norm".

Say that a norm is discrete if its range in $\Bbb R$ is a discrete set.

> **Exercise.** If $G$ is a free-abelian group, then it has a discrete norm.
>
> **Difficult theorem.** If $G$ has a discrete norm, then it is free-abelian.

The only known proof uses Shelah's compactness theorem for singular cardinals. So quite significant heavy machinery from set theory and model theory combined.

Answer (score 15):

Turning my comment into an answer. Given a group $G$ we can define its dual group $G^\ast=\mathrm{Hom}(G,\Bbb Z)$ and, just like for vector spaces, we get a canonical "evaluation" homomorphism $G\to G^{\ast\ast}$ given by $g\mapsto(f\mapsto f(g))$ and we call reflexive the groups for which this homomorphism is an isomorphism.

> **Theorem:** Every free abelian group is reflexive iff there is no measurable cardinal.

I'll prove the $\implies$ direction, the other one is not as easy. Let $\kappa$ be measurable, and let $\mathcal U$ a $\kappa$-complete nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\kappa$.
Consider the free Abelian group $\Bbb Z^{(\kappa)}=\bigoplus_{i<\kappa}\Bbb Z$ with its standard basis $\{e_\xi\}_{\xi<\kappa}$ and note that $\mathrm{Hom}(\Bbb Z^{(\kappa)},\Bbb Z)\simeq\Bbb Z^\kappa$.
Consider the function $\varphi\colon\Bbb Z^\kappa\to\Bbb Z$ given by $\varphi(x)=n$ iff $\{\xi\in\kappa\mid x(\xi)=n\}\in \mathcal U$, we claim that this function is not in the image of the canonical homomorphism $j\colon\Bbb Z^{(\kappa)}\to(\Bbb Z^{(\kappa)})^{\ast\ast}\simeq (\Bbb Z^\kappa)^\ast$, indeed for every nonzero $x\in\Bbb Z^{(\kappa)}$ we have $j(x)(e_\xi)=x(\xi)\neq 0$ for some $\xi$, but $\varphi(e_\xi)=0$ for every $\xi$. (in the identification $(\Bbb Z^{(\kappa)})^\ast\simeq \Bbb Z^k$, $e_\xi$ corresponds to the projection $\Bbb Z^\kappa\to\Bbb Z$ on the $\xi$-th factor).

A reference for the proof of the other direction (actually of a much more general result which trivially implies the other direction) is Corollary III.3.8 in the beautiful book "Almost free modules: set theoretic methods", by Eklof and Mekler.

Answer (score 11):

There's the Whitehead problem : let $A$ be an abelian group such that any extension $0\to \mathbb Z\to K\to A\to 0$ (with $K$ abelian) splits.

Is $A$ then necessarily a free abelian group ?

The question is famously independent of ZFC, so depends on set theory.

Comment: Of course, indeed a famous case of independence. I'm not sure, though, that a first-year undergraduate who has only done a short algebra course is going to "see" the Whitehead problem as a natural question to raise (which is why I didn't mention it).